# Flex scrolling more than 10.000 pixels

Tags: apache-flex, canvas

The Flex Canvas container is limited to 10,000x10,000 pixels. Yet, I've seen Flex apps that are scrolling way more than 10,000 pixels. Any idea how this can be done?

The content I want to scroll is in pieces already, but I need to add those pieces to something that can scroll vertically more than 10,000 pixels.

Comment: Actually Canvas has no such limitation as 10kx10k max size. How did you come up with that?

Comment: Hey, you're right! Funny thing; if you go to read about Canvas, it recommends using 2 Spark containers, and they are both limited to 10kx10k...very strange. thanks.

Comment: I've not actually done much Flex 4 programming but from some code snippets I wrote to test that 10kx10k limitation, I can clearly see that Group is not limited in any way either - it will happily set itself to, say, 20k height.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you actually want to display you may be able to split your content into tiles. This is how Google Maps works, every time the map is moved the program determines which tiles are visible on the screen and loads them in. Any markers or overlays that are on the map are notified that the map has moved and determine where their new location is. If their location is off the screen they can be removed from the canvas. For example, the width of all the tiles at zoom level 20 on Google Maps is (256 pixels * 2^20) which equals 268,435,456 total pixels.

Essentially you just need to create a special Sprite that keeps track of the actual x,y location it is supposed to be positioned at. Any time the container moves you simply iterate through all of the child objects and determine where to put them.

```
function onCanvasScroll() {
    //determine the top left coordinates of the canvas
    //you will figure out how to do this depending on how the scrolling window
    //is implemented
    var canvas_scroll_x;
    var canvas_scroll_y;

    //create a bounding box for the canvas
    var view_bounds = new Rectangle(canvas_scroll_x, canvas_scroll_y, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    for (child in canvas) {
        var x = child.actual_x - view_bounds.x;
        var y = child.actual_y - view_bounds.y;

        var childBounds = new Rectangle(x, y, child.width, child.height);
        //determine if the component is visible on screen
       if (view_bounds.intersects(child_bounds)) {
          child.visible = true;
          child.x = x;
          child.y = y;
       }
       else {
           child.visible = false;
       }

    }
}
```

So if you have a canvas that is positioned at (100, 20000), a sprite that is positioned at (300, 20100), and a window that is (640,408), you would place it at (200, 100) and it would be visible on the screen.

Instead of just setting visible to true or false a better approach would be to remove the items from the canvas entirely when they are not within the bounds of the view.

Comment: Hello. Interesting. I have not tried this yet. But I am wondering about the scroll bars. How will they resize and scroll to match the content?

Comment: I should think would have to determine the size of the content and the set the size of the scroll bars manually. If the scrollbars are not actually bound to the canvas then I should think you can just change the size of the sliders. My experience is with plain actionscript rather than flex so I am not sure how flex works in that regard.